# Caluclating CPU utilization for a web application running in gunicorn with 4 workers and 4 threads

Tags: python-3.x, gunicorn, psutil

I have a web application running in gunicorn server with 4 workers and 4 threads,
i am using psutil to fetch the cpu utilization as follows

```
process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
while True:
   print("cpu Utilization",process.cpu_percent(interval=0)/psutil.cpu_count())
```

the above code will print cpu percent of each workers pids with cpu_cores

1. if i want to get overall cpu utilization of the application, how can i get it,
2. and if the application or process is using only 2 or 3 cpu cores.(psutil.Process().cpu_affinity())  then should i need to caluclate cpu percent by dividing with num of used cores

Comment: if you deployed on k8s, the `cpu` is node so the cpu from `os.getpid()` is incorrect. You dont need to get overall cpu to set worker, the number of workers depends on what application you are processing `cpu bound` or `io bound` and `vcpu` that you can provide for server. It's better for increasing worker and stress test